# PHP Sending mail with Outlook

Tags: php, html, email, outlook, phpmailer

there is my code (it's works for gmail account but not with outlook)
I change Host, SMTPDebug(from 0 to 2),Port(from 465 to 587) but it doesn't work

```
    $mailto = $mail;
    $mailSub = "Invitation";
    $mailMsg = "Bonjour $nom  $prenom de cin: $CIN, <br> Votre entretien est 
    le $date à $heure <br> Merci d'être à l heure <br> Cordialement ";
    require '../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSmtp();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
    $mail->Port = 587; 

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "*******@******";
    $mail->Password = "*********";
    $mail->setFrom("*****@******");
    $mail->Subject = $mailSub;
    $mail->Body = $mailMsg;
    $mail->AddAddress($mailto);
    $mail->Send();
```

Comment: if it works for gmail + not outlook - surely is account details issue?

Comment: i checked it many times ... i copied to be more sure but it doesn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Outlook.com SMTP server address: smtp-mail.outlook.com**

Try this with your host.
And for sending to outlook mails. I suggest you go through this website. Website includes ports to SMTP, password, server, SSL, address.

https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-outlook-com-smtp-server-settings-1170671

Comment: i modified       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; and it s worked. Thanks !!

Comment: Well, Glad to help. Your Welcome!!

Answer (score 3):

i just replaced this line and it's worked:

```
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

to this:

```
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Comment: equivalent constants are  `'ssl'` aka `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS`, `tls` aka `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`, calling tls starttls is hugely misleading, unless 'tls' isn't tls and is actually starttls...

Answer (score 0):

Juste comment this one :
//$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;

```
     //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER; 
    $mail->isSMTP();          
                                     
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;         
    $mail->Username   = 'xxxxxxxxx@outlook.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxxxx';                               //SMTP password
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS; //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                      //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('xxxxx@outlook.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('xxxx@gmail.com');               //Name is optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```